# Oracle PLSQL - Update based on non-null

Tags: oracle, plsql, null, sql-update

I have a PLSQL Procedure that receives

```
FUNCTION VALIDATE_UPDATE_REQUEST (P_Orderno In Ord_Head.Order_No%Type,
P_First_Name In Ord_Address.First_Name%Type,
P_Last_Name  In Ord_Address.Last_Name%Type,
P_Address In Ord_Address.Add_1%Type,
P_Mobile In Ord_Address.Phone_No%Type)
```

First Name, Last Name, Address, Mobile, Order No

The four parameters: First Name, Last Name, Address, Mobile
can be NULL or cannot be NULL

If they are NOT NULL, I need to update the table with whatever is not null in the parameters

How do I do that?

eg:

```
First Name: Robert
Last Name: NULL
Mobile: NULL
Add1 : First Street, 20A
```

Based on this, I only need to update First Name and Add1 in the table Ord_Address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummmm ... no, you don't have a function. That should be a **procedure** as functions can't do DML operations.

Other than that, procedure would have something like this:

```
update your_table set
  first_name = nvl(p_first_name, first_name),
  last_name  = nvl(p_last_name, last_name),
  address    = nvl(p_address, address),
  mobile     = nvl(p_mobile, mobile)
where orderno = p_orderno;
```